# How to create form for nested resource with has_many through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble creating the correct form_with syntax to create a record for a has_many through association and cannot find an example to copy.

My model has a Factory.  Factories can have Equipment.  Equipment can have many EquipmentVariations. Variations are specific to a particular type of equipment, but are different for each specific piece of equipment (so the VariationType is associated with the EquipmentType)

I can create the factory (e.g. localhost/factories/1)
I can create the equipment at the factory (e.g. localhost/factories/1/equipment/1)

But I cannot manage to make a form that creates EquipmentVariations.  That is, when I navigate to localhost/factories/1/equipment/1 I want a form to add EquipmentVariations to that Equipment entry.

Here's my code:

routes.rb

```
    resources :factories do
        resources :equipment do
            resources :equipment_variations
        end
    end

    resources :equipment_types do
        resources :variation_types
    end
```

Models

```
class Factory < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :equipment
end

class Equipment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :factory
    belongs_to :equipment_type
    has_many :equipment_variations
    has_many :variation_types, through: :equipment_variations
end

class EquipmentVariation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :equipment
  belongs_to :variation_type
end

class VariationType < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :equipment_type
    has_many :equipment_variations
    has_many :equipment, through: :equipment_variations
end
```

And the view in app/views/equipment/show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @equipment.equipment_type.name %></h1>

<h3>Add Variation</h3>
<%= form_with(model: [@equipment, VariationType.new], url: factory_equipment_equipment_variations_path, local: true) do |form| %>

<%= form.submit %>

<% end %>
```

This is as close as I have been able to manage, but gives the error: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"equipment_variations", :factory_id=>"2", :id=>"3"}, missing required keys: [:equipment_id]

Basically, I need to be able to post to the URL /factories/1/equipment/1/equipment_variations from the page at /factories/1/equipment/1.  The route given for that is factory_equipment_equipment_variations which is why I specified that in the url parameter, but I feel there must be a simpler way to acheive this.  What should the form_with parameters look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured this out.  I was close, but the correct syntax is as follows

```
<%= form_with(model: [@factory, @equipment, EquipmentVariation.new], local: true) do |form| %>
```

So you need to give the model: parameter all the models for the route (factory, equipment) and it will figure out the correct path by itself and submit the parameters appropriately.

Also, my controller for EquipmentVariation called by above looks like:

```
def create
        @equipment = Equipment.find(params[:equipment_id])
        @equipment.variation_types << VariationType.find(params[:variation_type][:variation_type_id])
    end
```

Hope this helps someone in future!